# Huffman algorithm from Cormen

Tags: c++, algorithm, huffman-code

I'm trying to write a [Huffman coding tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding), by using `multimap<int, NODE*>` where `NODE` is just a classical tree node.
So I have written this method:

```
this->CreateMapTree();
int n = (int)tree.size();
pair<int, NODE*> x, y, z;

for (int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i)
{
    x = *tree.begin(); tree.erase(tree.begin());
    y = *tree.begin(); tree.erase(tree.begin());

    z.second = new NODE;

    z.second->left = y.second;
    z.second->right = x.second;
    z.first = x.first + y.first;

    tree.insert(z);
}//after loop there is only one element in the tree


head = tree.begin()->second;
```

Method `CreateMapTree` work perfect, as the result I have `tree`.
I used classical algorithm of сreating Huffman tree (from Cormen). I was checking this code many times, but I couldn't find my mistake. Code three is wrong and I can't create correct dictionary for encode and decode.

What is wrong?

Comment: So, uh, what actually is the problem? If you dropped in your implementation for `CreateMapTree` and `NODE` so the code snippet could be compiled and run, it might be easier to offer advice.

Comment: Problem - wrong tree. Program is compiled successfully

Comment: Yeah, but what's wrong with it? It's not Huffman? Contains garbage? ..?

Comment: What does "Code Three is wrong" mean?  What frequencies are you giving it, and what are you expecting?  What is not correct about the "dictionary" you are creating?

Comment: It's just wrong, I have the same code for different symbols

Comment: So you can't even explain whats wrong? How are we supposed to help?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at what happens to x and y after you delete them from the tree. Pointers to them may no longer be valid.